# Present staff hierarchy graphically which has no top level

Tags: c#, d3.js

A typical staff hierarchy would look something like this with at least one root.

```
+----------+----------+
| Employee | Manager  |
+----------+----------+
| Person A |          |
| Person B | Person A |
| Person C | Person A |
| Person D | Person A |
| Person E | Person A |
| Person F | Person B |
| Person G | Person B |
| Person H | Person B |
| Person I | Person B |
| Person J | Person B |
| Person K | Person B |
+----------+----------+
```

Which looks like this in graphviz

[image]

My problem is that my data has now changed and there is no root because Person A/Person B manage each other:

```
+----------+----------+
| Employee | Manager  |
+----------+----------+
| Person A | Person B |
| Person B | Person A |
| Person C | Person A |
| Person D | Person A |
| Person E | Person A |
| Person F | Person B |
| Person G | Person B |
| Person H | Person B |
| Person I | Person B |
| Person J | Person B |
| Person K | Person B |
+----------+----------+
```

[image]

Whilst I am questioning the validity of this it made me wonder how I can work with this data to represent it graphically similar to graphviz using C#/d3.js

I believe the problem lies with the model I am building, the code below is expecting there to be at least one root so doesn't return anything. If there are no roots I think I need to calculate a depth or weighting to work out roughly where the top of the hierarchy is but I'm not sure where to start.

```
public static class AssignmentNodeEnumerable
{
    public static IList<AssignmentNode> BuildTree(this IEnumerable<AssignmentNode> source)
    {
        var assignments = source.GroupBy(i => i.SupervisorPersonId);

        var roots = assignments.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false).ToList();

        if (roots.Count > 0)
        {
            var dict = assignments.Where(g => g.Key.HasValue).ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Value, g => g.ToList());
            for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(roots[i], dict);
        }

        return roots;
    }

    private static void AddChildren(AssignmentNode node, IDictionary<int, List<AssignmentNode>> source)
    {
        if (source.ContainsKey(node.PersonId))
        {
            node.Children = source[node.PersonId];
            for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(node.Children[i], source);
        }
        else
        {
            node.Children = new List<AssignmentNode>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: conceptually you could argue you've got 2 roots, rather than none.

Comment: "Whilst I am questioning the validity of this" If you have a company owned by two partners, it makes good sense for the partners to sign off on each other's expenses and holidays, and do each other's appraisals.  They could not bother with these things, but it keeps everyone honest, and encourages a "we are all in this together" attitude.